# Android Quick Contextual bar on textview

Tags: android, action

In Android if the textview is selected then a word gets selected and a contextual action bar comes at the top...i want to modify that CAB and make it look like a quick action bar...keeping the text selection feature intact...please help me...

Answer (score 1):

you can select textview or anything like only in simple layout CAB appear in the top and there was some method onActionItemClicke that you want to click an item and then you modify your action in CAB default behavior................................

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
protected Object mActionMode;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    View view = findViewById(R.id.lay);
    view.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        // Called when the user long-clicks on someView
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
          if (mActionMode != null) {
            return false;
          }

          mActionMode = MainActivity.this.startActionMode(mActionModeCallback);
              view.setSelected(true);
              return true;
            }
          });
        }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
  Toast.makeText(this, "Just a test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  return true;
}
private ActionMode.Callback mActionModeCallback = new ActionMode.Callback() {

    // Called when the action mode is created; startActionMode() was called
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
      // Inflate a menu resource providing context menu items
      MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
      // Assumes that you have "contexual.xml" menu resources
      inflater.inflate(R.menu.cab, menu);
      return true;
    }

    // Called each time the action mode is shown. Always called after
    // onCreateActionMode, but
    // may be called multiple times if the mode is invalidated.
    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
      return false; // Return false if nothing is done
    }

    // Called when the user selects a contextual menu item
    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
      switch (item.getItemId()) {
      case R.id.toast:
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Selected menu",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        mode.finish(); // Action picked, so close the CAB
        return true;
      case R.id.shan:
          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Selected shani",
                  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              mode.finish(); // Action picked, so close the CAB
              return true;
      default:
        return false;
      }
    }

    // Called when the user exits the action mode
    public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
      mActionMode = null;
    }
  };
```

}

```
and in menu xml file create menu that you would like to appear in top CAB



    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
  <item
    android:id="@+id/toast"
    android:title="Toast">
</item>
 <item
    android:id="@+id/shan"
    android:title="shani">
</item>
   </menu>
```